# Add feature to existing layer in Geotools

Tags: java, geotools

I add a layer to a Geotools MapPane, consisting of various WKT String features.  The layer is displayed correctly.  Now, at the click of a button on the UI, I want to add another feature to this layer.

Initially, I create the layer and display it using the following:

```
List<SimpleFeature> list  = featuresFromWkt(wktString, name); //method name explains what it does..
ListFeatureCollection col = new ListFeatureCollection(getFeatureType(), list); 
Color color = Color.BLUE;
Style style = SLD.createPolygonStyle(color, color.brighter(), 0.5f);
FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(col, style);
layer.setVisible(true);
layer.setTitle(name);
mapContent.layers().add(layer)
```

Now, to add something to the layer, I get the layer from the content, using:

```
FeatureLayer layer = (FeatureLayer) mapContent.layers().get(0);
```

I can now use layer.getSimpleFeatureSource() to retrieve the source, but there seems to be no way to cast this source back to something I can call a .addFeature(someNewFeature) on to add something to the map.

I can keep a reference to the ListFeatureCollection and use that to add new features, but I would prefer to only use the mapConent.layers.get(layerNumber) approach and then use the layer to add stuff.

All the samples I have seen thus far just add another layer with the new features.  I do not want to add another layer, rather just add something to the existing layer, of which the content sits in memory. Am I missing something here?  Is there a GeoTools class I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Adding-geometry-to-layer-td4324729.html. This sounds very similar to your problem and was asked a while ago on the GeoTools mailing list.

Basic idea, in case the mailing list archive linked above becomes unavailable at some point in time:

- Create a feature collection containing your features (might be empty initially)
- add this feature collection to a map layer
- add features later to the feature collection.

According to the statement on the mailing list: "The map pane should repaint automagically when you add features to the collection (there is a chain of events sent from the feature collection to the map layer to the layer list to the map pane)"

Comment: Thanks. I came to the same conclusion a couple of minutes ago.  I extended the FeatureLayer class and keep a reference to the feature collection in this new class.   Then, from the MapContent, I get the Layer, cast it to my new class and call an .addFeature(feature) method.
The .addFeature method just ads the feature to the collection.

It does seem a bit dirty, but works for me by allowing me to add stuff by getting the layer from the mapContent.  Hopefully it won't bite me later :)

Comment: Not working so good here: the layer is updated only once in a while, moreover I API is not extremely consistent: `SimpleFeatureCollections#contains()` and `SimpleFeatureCollections#add()` are based on the feature ID, while `SimpleFeatureCollections#remove()` is based on the full feature hash, which would result in features not removed because of a change in some attribute. I gues I'll remove/add the layer to achieve real-time.  ?